# Why does this print 0?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

i am experimenting with go concurrency and i was trying a few patterns.
i was trying this where you receive an array of elements, process them concurrently and sum all the results.
i am using 2 channels, one to process the array and the other to sum the results.
To synchronize this i am using a waitgroup to wait until all the elements are processed an then close the channel.
But my surprise is when this code prints 0.
I am new to go but i don't understand why is it printing 0.
Can someone explain?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    input := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    c := make(chan int)
    result := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    go process_all(input, c, &wg)
    go sum_results(c, result)

    wg.Wait()
    close(c)

    sum := <- result
    fmt.Println(sum)
}

func sum_results(c chan int, res chan int) {
    var sum int
    for result := range c {
        sum += result
    }
    res <- sum
}

func process_all(inputs []int, c chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(len(inputs) + 1)
    defer wg.Done()
    for input := range inputs {
        go process_input(input, c, wg)
    }
}

func process_input(input int, c chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    c <- input * 2
}
```

i would expect this to print 20

Comment: `wg` count is 0 when `main` reaches `wg.Wait()`, and so it __doesn't wait__; call wg.Add(1) __before__ the `go process_all` and remove `+ 1` from inside `process_all`. Note: inside `process_all` the `input` iteration variable is the index, not the element of the `inputs` slice, you should probably use `inputs[i]` or `_, input := range`: https://go.dev/play/p/GdE0MmavLdM

Comment: The go routine ` go process_all(input, c, &wg)` did not finish before main function finish?

Answer (score 4):

There's two errors in your program that I can see. First, you call `wg.Add` inside the first goroutine, so there's no guarantee that it's been called when you `wg.Wait`, thus closing the channel c before anything gets added to it. Secondly, the range over `inputs` gives the indexes rather than the values in the slice.

Comment: so go is launching the goroutine but it's not executing the first line, causing the Wait() to execute and printihg 0 right?

Comment: Something like that yes